# Passing output variables between Azure Devops build pipeline steps, for example 7 digit git hash

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, build-pipeline

I am trying to include the 7-digit git hash in the artifact name built by my Azure Devops build pipeline. In my build agent job I have an inline powershell script with the following lines:

```bsh
$commitId = "$(Build.SourceVersion)"
$shortCommitId = ("$commitId").SubString(0,7)
```

In the options for the Powershell script under "Output variables" I add a reference name: `ps`.

Then in the Publish Artifact step right after my Powershell step I set the artifact name as:

```
$(ApplicationName)_Rel_$(ps.shortCommitId)_$(build.buildnumber)
```

The actual result after the pipeline has finished running is:

```
MyApplication_Rel_$(ps.shortCommitId)_20190918.1
```

How do I pass the variable shortCommitId between steps so that it will be part of the artifact name? `MyApplication_Rel_04f53f_20190918.18`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add another line that create a variable to the next steps:

```
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=shortCommitId;]$shortCommitId"
```

In the Publish Artifacts task use the varaible `$(shortCommitId)`:

```
$(ApplicationName)_Rel_$(shortCommitId)_$(build.buildnumber)
```

Another option, if you want to use it as an output varaible, is to add `isOutput=true`:

```
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=shortCommitId;isOutput=true]$shortCommitId"
```

And now you can use the `$(ps.shortCommitId)`.